# Finding an object.member from another class

Tags: java

I have a public class 'Tree' with two members, Tree.id and Tree.description.  I've created 100 Tree objects, each Tree having a unique id(a counter) and a description.

I have another class called 'List'. I want to search on Tree.id using a counter and return Tree.description.  The idea is to have a while loop in List with a counter variable, when the counters match, the value of Tree.description is returned to a temp variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: I should have used different class names, List and Tree are just names of the classes, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a public getter to id and for description in the Tree class.
2. Create a `List<Tree> trees` in the other class and put the Trees in there.
3. Loop thorough the list and search for match by id.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question looks like homework or some type of exercise, I will only provide a pseudo code on how to do this, **no code at all**.

Traverse through the elements of your list (array, `List` or whatever you're using) and do the filter using an `if` statement. If you find the desired id, return the description, otherwise, keep looping. If no item was found, return an empty `String` (or something else):

```
public String get(int id)
    for every Tree tree in List
        if tree.id is equal to id
            return tree.description
        end if
    end for
    return ""
end public
```